# Maximal rectangle set cover

Tags: algorithm, set

I've got a binary matrix and I'm trying to find all the largest rectangles that can be formed by adjoining elements in the matrix.  By largest rectangles I mean, all the rectangles which are unique, non subsets of any other rectangles.  For example, the following matrix contains six such rectangles.

[image]

This is related to the set cover problem, though here I'm interested in the maximum number of rectangles, not the minimum.  An approach I've tried is to find all the rectangles regardless of size, then compare rectangles and remove them if they are a subset of another rectangle.  This is not an optimal approach.  It seems like this case of the set cover problem shouldn't be too hard.

I've had a look and not found anything similar to this problem.  There is [this](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~cjulia/papers/rectangles-SODA.pdf) paper, which has some good ideas, but still wide of the mark.  Is there another name for this particular problem?  Are there any existing algorithms for finding all possible rectangles in a set cover problem?

Comment: How many rectangles are there in the matrix with rows `101, 000, 101`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Four.  A single isolated element would count as a rectangle.  Edit: Though in my circumstance 1's would always be contiguous.

Comment: I suspect that there's an (output-sensitive) linear-time algorithm that uses the ideas from the classic algorithm to find the maxim*um* rectangle.

Comment: If you write a graph where all the possible rectangles are nodes and there is an edge between them if a rectangle is contained in another, the problem can be solved by finding the maximum independent set (also known as vertex packing). But this is an NP-hard problem. This doesn't prove NP-hardness of your problem, but would give you a hint.

Comment: My guess is O(n^2), where n is the number of entries in the matrix.  O(n^3) is pretty simple, just check each of the O(n^2) rectangles (it takes O(n) time to check a rectangle naively) and extend them by one in every direction to see if they are maximal.  You can find a single maximal rectangle in O(n), so it seems like you should be able to find them all in O(n^2).  The question is whether there is something you can exploit to find them all faster.

Comment: @mrip If you think you can propose a O(n^3) algorithm, please elaborate an answer, because I just can't think of any. Also, there are O(n^4) rectangles in a nxn matrix.

Comment: @Juan Lopes I'm treating n as the total number of entries (so this would be n^2 in your terminology).

Comment: Just adding more info for people trying to answer: the resulting graph represents a partially ordered set, and the vertex packing can be computed in polynomial time using the Dilworth's theorem. I'd try to write a proof-of-concept, but it's just too late here. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I think some variation on finding the largest rectangle is probably the best solution here.  I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more work, I've realised this is not really related to the set cover problem.  It's actually the 'finding the unique rectangles that are not contained within in any other rectangle in a binary matrix problem'.

I have come up with something that works well, but I have no idea about it's complexity.

Basically, line sweep across the matrix horizontally and vertically.  In each case, look for contiguous groups of 1's that can form rectangles with the next line.  This results in a number of rectangles, some of which are duplicates or sub rectangles of others.  These rectangles are reduced to a unique set where no rectangle is a sub rectangle of another.  Then you have all the rectangles.

Here is a diagram that relates to the image in the original post:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i dont speek english very wheel but, maximal rectangles overlapping is a problem that resolve many pb, if you somme maximal rectangles, geometrique sommation you find  optimal volume that you derive to find queleton etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).